# Concatenation with a complex query - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, concatenation, coalesce

So I've got a query with multiple joins and several rows that I want to put on one line. A couple of PIVOT statements solved most of this problem, but I have one last field with multiple rows (User Names) that I want to concatenate into one column.

I've read about COALESCE and got a sample to work, but I did not know how to combine the variable returned with the other data fields, as it has no key.

I also saw this recommended approach:

```
SELECT  [ID],
  STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + CAST([Name] AS VARCHAR(MAX))
    FROM #YourTable WHERE (ID = Results.ID) 
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE 
     /* Use .value to uncomment XML entities e.g. &gt; &lt; etc*/
    ).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)') 
  ,1,2,'') as NameValues
FROM    #YourTable Results
GROUP BY ID
```

But again, I'm not sure how to incorporate this into a complex query.

BTW, the users do not have write access to the DB, so cannot create functions, views, tables or even execute functions. So this limits the options somewhat.

Comment: Show db schema, sample data and expected result. Your query doesnt say much why isnt working?. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: A little more context would be helpful (ie sample data and desired results),  Also, very smart of you to express the limitations imposed on you

Comment: The `FOR XML` approach should work in your situation, though without additional information as previously requested, you are going to get little to no useful help.